# Unable to click on button of a pop-up in div using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button inside pop-up. However, webdriver always throws No such element exception.
The pop-up is not an alert but a regular element defined inside a .
It consists of a message and an OK button. I'm able to verify / locate the message element but unable to click on the button.
Following is the html code for it.

```
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_6_1522928024187_16" class="yui3-widget modal yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked yui3-widget-modal yui3-resize" style="width: 95%; left: 334px; top: 167px; z-index: 0;" tabindex="0">
    <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_6_1522928024187_18" class="modal-content yui3-widget-stdmod">
        <div class="yui3-widget-hd modal-header">
            <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_6_1522928024187_112" class="toolbar-content yui3-widget component toolbar">
                <button type="button" class="btn close">×</button>
            </div>
            <h3>Message</h3></div>
        <div class="yui3-widget-bd modal-body">
            <div class="info-block">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="127">
                                <div id="info_image_errorPriceConditioNotSelect" class="info-image restriction-image"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="info_content_errorPriceConditioNotSelect" class="info-content">None selected</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="yui3-widget-ft modal-footer">
            <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_6_1522928024187_153" class="toolbar-content yui3-widget component toolbar">
                <button type="button" class="btn yui3-widget btn-content btn-focused" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_6_1522928024187_500">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yui3-resize-handles-wrapper">
        <div class="yui3-resize-handle yui3-resize-handle-br">
            <div class="yui3-resize-handle-inner yui3-resize-handle-inner-br">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my code through which I'm trying to access the button:-

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'yui_patched_v3_11_')]//div[@id="info_content_errorPriceConditioNotSelect"]"))));
    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'yui_patched_v3_11_')]//div[@id="info_content_errorPriceConditioNotSelect"]")).isDisplayed());
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@id,"yui_patched_v3_")][text()='OK']")).click(); //Webdriver throws exception here
```

I'm using selenium 3.9.1 and executing the scripts on chrome.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Anuja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is with XPATH. Try below code for OK button click.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")).click();
```

Comment: You are right! If I use any attribute other than text for this button element, it fails... I dont know why!!!

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is no alert but the active element at this Moment you see it. So I think, clicking on OK might be possible in this way:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().submit();
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Explicit wait to wait till the pop up is displayed rather than Thread.sleep().

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yui_patched_v3_11_0_6_1522928024187_500"))).click();
```

Comment: I had tried that as well. It does not work. I get TimeOutException

Answer (score 0):

The *pop-up* is actually a *Modal Dialog Box* so click on the button with text as **OK** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn yui3-widget btn-content btn-focused' and starts-with(@id,'yui_patched_v')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is incorrect**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@id,"yui_patched_v3_")][text()='OK']")).click();
```

Note, you are using double quotes for the `"yui_patched_v3_"` ID. This is terminating the xpath early. Convert to single quotes like you used for 'OK'.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@id,'yui_patched_v3_')][text()='OK']")).click();
```